# cant create truly asynchronous child process in django

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, subprocess

So I have a view that I can send an Http post or get. The post handler is set up to asynchronously create a child process, then return a string. The problem is that it seems to create the process, continue code execution, but then hang and wait for the subprocess to finish before returning the response. How can I get this to be truly asynchronous?

```
def post(self, request):
create_async_request()
return HttpResponse("done")

def create_async_request():
    p = Popen(['ping','localhost','-c','15']) #something that I know will take a couple secs
```

Comment: If this is your code, it isn't actually asynchronous. You should look at using threading.Thread.

Comment: the right way really would be to use something like celery.

Comment: @SamMussmann its an oversimplified version. I also used os.fork and got some weird results, put a print message inside post() and verified that the message was printed while the ping was happening. Does this (asynchronouss system call) have anything to do with django or is this just general python?

Comment: If you want to do things asynchronously, you'll need to call it in another thread, or use Celery or something.  This is more of a general python issue, although celery is a common solution when you're using django.